# How to remove a dependency in my NPM manifest?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

**Goal:** Create a CRA TypeScript app with Yarn.

I run `yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript` on my terminal. Then I encounter the ff. error message:

```
yarn create v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning create-react-app > tar-pack > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error create-strapi-app@3.6.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x". Got "16.14.2"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

And it's super weird and confusing because I'm not trying to create a Strapi project. I check `yarn-error.log` and I see these lines after the Error Stack Trace:

```
npm manifest: 
  {
    "dependencies": {
      "create-strapi-app": "^3.6.3"
    }
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest
```

So I'm thinking either CRA requires CSA, or somehow my local NPM is configured to always require CSA. I very much doubt the former, so I'm betting it's the latter. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.) Either way, any ideas how I may resolve this?

Comment: Same problem. I removed all strapi packages on my system, bu still I can't create react app :(

Comment: Hey, @YusufUlusoy. I worked around it by adding `--ignore-engines` to my yarn cmd:
`yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript --ignore-engines`. But now I have to add it every time I need to use CRA. Still hoping someone could answer how to fully resolve this.